# Does Dart reuse DateTime instances?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-widget

I'm fiddling around with `GlobalObjectKey`, where my objects are `DateTime` instances. I noticed that if I create new instances of the same date and time, I get the same instance "ID":

```
DateTime newInstance = new DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(datetime.microsecondsSinceEpoch);
```

My debug prints say that there are two separate keys with the same id:

```
[GlobalObjectKey DateTime#f056e] // Key assigned to Widget1
[GlobalObjectKey DateTime#f056e] // Key assigned to Widget2
```

However, even though the keys seem to be duplicates, I don't seem to get any widget/build errors.

Here's a more complete example of what I'm doing:

```
class DateTimeKey{
  GlobalObjectKey key;
  DateTimeKey(DateTime datetime){
    DateTime newInstance = new DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(datetime.microsecondsSinceEpoch);
    key = new GlobalObjectKey(newInstance);
  }
}

...

List<DateTimeKey> _bookingListMonthKeys = [];
List<DateTimeKey> _bookingListDayKeys = [];

DateTimeKey _monthKey = new DateTimeKey(theDate);
_bookingListMonthKeys.add(_monthKey);

DateTimeKey _dayKey = new DateTimeKey(theDate); // theDate here refers to the same DateTime instance as above
_bookingListDayKeys.add(_dayKey);
```

Even if I loop through both lists and cross reference them like this

```
  _bookingListDayKeys.forEach((dayKey){
    _bookingListMonthKeys.forEach((monthKey){
      if( identical(dayKey, monthKey) )
        print('Identical DateTimeKeys found: $dayKey, $monthKey');

      if( identical(dayKey.key, monthKey.key) )
        print('Identical GlobalObjectKeys found: ${dayKey.key}, ${monthKey.key}');
    });
  });
```

it doesn't show any duplicates, yet the printouts above clearly have the same "id" (`#f056e`). Can someone explain what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I figured out what's going on here.

First, the hash number in the question comes from the [hashCode](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/Object/hashCode.html) property of the `DateTime` instance. This is used for comparisons by the [== operator](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/Object/operator_equals.html), and hence will be the same for two `DateTime` instances that represent the same moment in time.

*Sidenote: The actual string being printed (`#f056e`) seems to be the last 5 characters of the hexadecimal representation of the `hashCode`, which is an `int`.*

However, `hashCode` is not used by `GlobalObjectKey`. Instead, it uses the method [identityhashCode()](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/identityHashCode.html) from `dart:core`:

> Returns the identity hash code of object.
>
> Returns the same value as object.hashCode if object has not overridden Object.hashCode. > Returns the value that Object.hashCode would return on this object, even if hashCode has > been overridden.
>
> This hash code is compatible with identical.

When creating two different `DateTime` instances from the same moment in time, their `hashCode` properties will be equal but the result of `identityHashCode()` will be different. So basically it seems like `identityHashCode()` is the closest substitute for an actual "memory address" of an object we will get.

```
DateTime instance1 = DateTime.now();
DateTime instance2 = DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(instance1.microsecondsSinceEpoch);
print('hashCode: ${instance1.hashCode}, ${instance2.hashCode}   identityHashCode: ${identityHashCode(instance1)}, ${identityHashCode(instance2)}');
```

will result in:

```
I/flutter (23321): hashCode: 89064814, 89064814   identityHashCode: 383428552, 594747591
```

Now it's clear to see that the `hashCode` is equal for both instances, but `identityHashCode(DateTime)` is different, meaning that they are in fact separate instances but equal when comparing their `hashCode` property or doing a `==` operation.

Why printing a `GlobalObjectKey` would print the `hashCode` of its value is still beyond me though, that's what threw me off from the start.